# How to control the location of a global variable in LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, code-generation, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to modify LLVM so that it keeps certain constants and functions contiguous in memory.
In other words, I need to ensure that the machine codes for certain functions are *always* preceded by some ~4-byte constant in memory. *The function body itself must not be modified.*

Could I achieve this simply through modifying the LLVM IR somehow?

- If yes:
  How would I state in the LLVM IR to keep a variable and a function contiguous in memory?
- If no:
  What part of the code generation process (i.e. which pass(es)) should I modify in order to achieve this? Any links to the projects/files I should look at would be helpful, since I'm not sure where to begin yet.

Comment: This will obviously work on non-Harvard architectures such as x86, but on an Harvard architecture such as Atmel this doesn't make sense. The bytes preceding code are also code; the bytes following data are also data. And I think LLVM is portable enough to support Harvard architectures.

Comment: @MSalters: Yeah... but that doesn't mean it *couldn't* have that functionality for non-Harvard architectures. It's not like it doesn't have platform-specific features after all (SSE, etc.). :) But if you know for a fact that it doesn't support this then please post it as an answer!

Comment: Is it related with TNTC optimization from GHC?

Comment: @arrowdodger: Nope... it's a project I'm working on.

Comment: Thoughts in this link can ve helpful: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4213

Comment: @arrowdodger: Oh wow that looks helpful, thanks a lot for the link! :)

Comment: You have to modify your platform backend, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think you can do that by just modifying the IR; you'd have to write something to handle it, yourself. It shouldn't be a pass, either - it's too low-level, it should run during the [target-specific code generation](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html). You can piggyback on an existing target and just modify this aspect, of course, you don't have to write a new target from scratch. I don't know which location exactly will be good for this, though.

I think a good way to pass this information from the IR level to the DAG during the code generation would be using metadata: attach metadata to either the function or the associated constant that will link them with each other, then later on use that link for emitting them together. See [this thread on llvm-dev for information how to transfer the metadata](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2010-September/034464.html).